# How to display /proc/meminfo in Megabytes?

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, text-processing, unit-conversion

I want to thank you for helping me my related issue. I know if I do a cat `/proc/meminfo` it will only display in kB. How can I display in MB? I really want to use `cat` or `awk` for this please.

Answer (score 45):

This will convert any `kB` lines to `MB`:

```
awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024;$3="MB"} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
```

This version converts to gigabytes:

```
awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024^2;$3="GB";} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
```

For completeness, this will convert to MB or GB as appropriate:

```
awk '$3=="kB"{if ($2>1024^2){$2=$2/1024^2;$3="GB";} else if ($2>1024){$2=$2/1024;$3="MB";}} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
```

Comment: How would i go about doing it in GB

Comment: For Debian based users, this may not work - If so, try replacing the `**` with `^`, or  replace `1024**2` with the result: `1048576`

Comment: @Addison Interesting.  It works fine for me under Debian with GNU awk but not under `mawk`.  I checked and `^` is [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) while `**` is not.  So, for greatest compatibility, I updated the answer, as per your suggestion, to use `^`.   Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`numfmt` tool](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html)

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | numfmt --field 2 --from-unit=Ki --to-unit=Mi | sed 's/ kB/M/g'
MemTotal:          128692M
MemFree:           17759M
MemAvailable:      119792M
Buffers:            9724M
...
$ cat /proc/meminfo | numfmt --field 2 --from-unit=Ki --to=iec | sed 's/ kB//g'
MemTotal:            126G
MemFree:             18G
MemAvailable:        118G
Buffers:            9.5G
...
$ cat /proc/meminfo | numfmt --field 2 --from-unit=Ki --to-unit=Gi | sed 's/ kB/G/g'
MemTotal:             126G
MemFree:              18G
MemAvailable:         117G
Buffers:              10G
...
```

Comment: Strongly more simple and clean. Thank you!

Comment: also works on container without 'column'

Answer (score 1):

Putting together [John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29811379/7650275) and tips from [shane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455513/7650275) into function:

```
if [ -f "/proc/meminfo" ]; then
  meminfo () {
    __meminfo=$(awk '$3=="kB"{if ($2>1024^2){$2=$2/1024^2;$3="GB";} else if ($2>1024){$2=$2/1024;$3="MB";}} 1' /proc/meminfo)
    echo "$__meminfo" | column -t;
    unset __meminfo;
  }
  HW_TOTALRAM=$(meminfo | awk '/MemTotal/ {printf "%.2f", $2; print $3}')
fi
```

[image: meminfo function result]

Comment: instead of setting then unset the variable you just need to use `local`

Comment: `local` is not available in POSIX, its a Bash feature/[bash-ism](https://betterprogramming.pub/24-bashism-to-avoid-for-posix-compliant-shell-scripts-8e7c09e0f49a). POSIX-compliant particularly helpful for barebones shells found in embedded devices.

Answer (score 0):

A single line bash entry for storing a memory quantity in MBs.
This is for `MemTotal` but works for others like MemFree.

```
MEM_TOTAL_MB=`awk '/MemTotal/ {printf( "%d\n", $2 / 1024 )}' /proc/meminfo`
```

Notes:

backtick (`` ` ``) and single quote (`'`) are used.

replace `%d` with `%.2f` if you want to display as a float with 2 decimal level precision.

Comment: backticks to get command output are deprecated. Use `$()` instead